# How to create an array that start and ends with given numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

```
let start = 2;
let finish = 6;

let arr = Array.from({length: finish}, (_, a) => a + 1);
```

Is there any way to incorporate the variable `start` so the array starts at this specific number and increases by 1 until it reaches the length?

the final result should be an array that starts with start value 2 increases by one and finishes when it reaches finish value 6. [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] in this case

Comment: I recommend trying to understand the `Array.from` expression that you already have. If you find unclear documentation for that function, please update here,

Comment: What should the final result be?

Comment: the final result should be an array that starts with start value 2 increases by one and finishes when it reaches finish value 6. [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] in this case!

Answer (score 3):

```js
Array.from(
  { length: finish - start },
  (_, i) => start + 1 + i
)
```

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation, naming things and one-off errors". ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const start = 18
const finish = 25
const arr = Array.from({length: finish - start + 1}, (_, a) => a + start);
console.log(arr) // [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

Answer (score -1):

Two alternatives to `Array.from`:

`Array(end - start + 1).fill(0).map((_, i) => start + i);`

`[...Array(end - start + 1)].map((_, i) => start + i);`

Remove the `+ 1` if `end` should be exclusive.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudocode:

```
arr = new int[finish - start + 1];
        
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = start++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use your "start" number:

```
let start = 2
let finish = 7
let arr = Array.from({length: finish}, (_, a) => a + start);
```